# How to connect other apps or service to access gmail account

Tags: gmail

I have an application which sends an email if an error occurs. I am using gmail account as from and to address. But when I run my program it gives me authentication required error. I got an email from google saying Sign-In attempt prevented. I also signed in for app password but it just worked once. When I see the apps connected to my account, the list is empty. How can connect app to my gmail account? How can I have this application access gmail account to send email.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the SMTP server of GMail to send e-mails.

- SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
- SMTP user name: Your full Gmail address (e.g. example@gmail.com)
- SMTP password: Your Gmail password

  - With Gmail 2-step authentication enabled, use an application-specific Gmail password.
- SMTP port (TLS): 587

  - SMTP port (SSL): 465
- SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes

Comment: its not js script i am just using jsfiddle to show the code

Answer (score 0):

You can let your application access your Gmail account by turning on "Access for less secure apps" to lower the security level.

It's a setting on the "My Account" page under Sign-in security. The link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps should take you there.